# Finding normal reaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

In the given figure,  find the normal reaction applied by surface OB and OC on spherical mass m = 10 kg as shown[image: Figure]

Comment: So what have you done? Showing your attempt might help someone to assist you.

Comment: i tried it but my answers came incorrect. My answers were 50(3)^(1/2) and 25(3)^(1/2). The correct answers are 100 and 100(3)^(1/2)

Comment: http://m.wikihow.com/Find-Normal-Force   scroll down to answer 2 , **how to find normal force on an incline**, or just Google that phrase

Comment: i know how to find normal reaction on a single inclined plane. But, there are two points of contacts. I don't know how to find both normal reactions

Comment: Does $OC$ have mass?

Comment: @Moulik , you need to work up a multi-step derivation on paper, and post it so people can tell where you are going wrong.  Also - and this is VERY important - stay SYMBOLIC as long as possible, THEN substitute numbers WITH ALL UNITS.  A string of numbers with no units, multiplied together, is all but meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Normal forces.]

Only three forces and no torques act on the sphere: $F_1$, $F_2$ and $mg$.

The sphere is stationary, so by Newton's second law there's **no net** force acting on the sphere.

Using basic trigonometry and the angles given, decompose all three forces into an $x$ (horizontal) and a $y$-component (vertical).

Newton then tells us:

$$\Sigma F_x=0$$
$$\Sigma F_y=0$$

This will give you a system of two simultaneous equations, which you need to solve for the Normal forces $F_1$ and $F_2$.